# Continuous dependence of eigenvalues on tangent-space endomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following setting:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and suppose that $T \colon M \to
> T^{(1,1)}(M)$ is a smooth section, that is, $T_x \in
> \mathrm{End}(T_xM)$ for every $x \in M$. Moreover, suppose that $T$ is
>   fibrewise symmetric and fibrewise positive. Hence we have
>   that the spectrum $\sigma(T_x)$ is contained in $(0,+\infty)$ for all
>   $x \in M$.

Now, for every $x_0 \in M$ there should be a neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $M$ such that the spectrum $\sigma(T_x)$ is contained in $[a_{x_0},b_{x_0}]$ with $a_{x_0} > 0$ for every $x$ in this neighbourhood. My reasoning is that this should follow from the continuous dependence of the roots of a polynomial of the coefficients. **Is that true?** Are there any good references on this (a book)? Because I've mostly found papaers on this subject.

Comment: Ordinarily we speak of a quadratic form as being positive-definite, not a linear map. How are you defining positive-definite? Just saying the eigenvalues are all positive?

Comment: But, yes, you're correct that, working in a local trivialization of the tangent bundle, this does just follow from the fact that the roots of a polynomial vary continuously in the coefficients. This is a standard exercise using Rouché's Theorem in complex analysis. It's an exercise in my multivariable mathematics text; I don't know of standard texts that give a proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh sorry, in the book that I am using it is written that $T_x$ is positive. But yes, this just means that all the eigenvalues are positive. Thank you! I will have a look at it since I did not find it in both of the textbooks I used in my studies on complex analysis.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've found a reference in the book *Numerical Analysis* by James M. Ortega (using Rouché's theorem).